# Python Extension for visual studio code not showing error or warning messages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-extensions

When i write **python** code on my **visual studio code editor** i can't find any **warnings** or **errors**.
I installed **python** extension,
I also change the **version** of that extension..
I also read many documentations of python extension and visual studio but can't find any solution
[Here is the image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhWqC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python code analysis tool "Pylint" or use "Microsoft" or "Pylance" language service in VS Code.

1. Python code analysis tool "Pylint".

   Please install the module "pylint" in the Python environment currently used in VS Code and enable its use settings.

   [Linting Python in Visual Studio Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)
2. Use "Microsoft" or "Pylance" language services.

Please use it in "settings.json":

```
  "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",`
```

or

```
 "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

[image]